# Tensorflow apply_gradients ValueError

Tags: tensorflow

I get the following error on second to last line of code: Not sure how to proceed. Can anyone give me some insight.

```
ValueError: Tensor("Variable_20:0", shape=(8, 8, 4, 32), dtype=float32_ref) must be from the same graph as Tensor("Variable_20/RMSProp_1:0", shape=(8, 8, 4, 32), dtype=float32_ref).
```

The code is as follows:

```
optimizer = tf.train.RMSPropOptimizer(0.00025, 0.95, 0.95, 0.01) 
readout = tf.reduce_mean(tf.reduce_sum(tf.mul(l_readout,a), reduction_indices=1))
cost  = tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(tf.sub(y,readout)))
grads = optimizer.compute_gradients(cost, localW)
grad_vals = sess.run([g for (g,v) in grads], feed_dict = {a: val_a, y: val_y, s: val_s})

placeholder_gradients = []
for var in localW:
    placeholder_gradients.append( (tf.placeholder('float',shape=var.get_shape()) , var) ) 

feed_dict = {}
for i in range(len(placeholder_gradients)):
    feed_dict[placeholder_gradients[i]] = grad_vals[i]

apply_gradients = optimizer.apply_gradients(placeholder_gradients) #ERROR LINE
apply_gradients.run(feed_dict=feed_dict)
```

Comment: Can you paste the entire code ?

Answer (score -1):

This maybe related to using a thread which is not shown in the example. I will withdraw this question until I look further into how to use threads with the same graph.